# How to specify different package requirements depending on operating system?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

How can I for a pip project specify that I need either package `foo` or package `bar` depending on what is available?

More specifically Tensorflow seems to ship in pip package named `tensorflow` for linux and a package named `tensorflow-macos` for Mac. How to make a pip package that can be installed on both platforms?

Seems the project is using setuptools, (it is not my project)

Comment: What packaging tools are you using? Setuptools or Poetry or?

Comment: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#platform-specific-dependencies

Comment: How are you defining your package's dependencies?